# Javascript how do i get my function array to give me more then the first value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function

```
function countUniqueItems(arr) {
  nums = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i];
    console.log(i);
    //console.log(item);
    if (nums.includes(arr) === true) {
      //console.log('8 is in the array');
      //nums.push(arr)
    } else {
      nums.push(arr);
      //console.log('8 is NOT in the array');
      //nums.push(item)
    }
  }
  return nums;
}
countUniqueItems(1, 2);
```

So it will give back the first argument which is 1 but i want it to be able to say argument 2 and 3 and so on

Comment: If I understand you question right, then just return an array or object from your function, also your function receives only one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to pass an array into the function, in place of 1,2 pass [1,2].

Then inside your function, you should use `arr.length` in place of `arguments.length`.

Then you look at your logic for the loop, you are pushing atm `arr` into nums, but if you pass and array that isn't really want you want, you should be pushing `item` as that is the variable which represents your current element from the array.

It looks from you comments like you're trying to make a unique list of inputs. Perhaps something like this would do the trick.

**EDIT:** Updated to use arguments

```js
function uniqueNumbers() {   
  
  let arrayOfArguments = [...arguments]
  
  let uniqueNums = []; 
  
  arrayOfArguments.map(i => !uniqueNums.includes(i) ? uniqueNums.push(i) : null); 
  
  return uniqueNums; 

}; 

console.log(uniqueNumbers(1,2,3,3));
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way i can parse it though without [1, 2]. I just realised for my solution i gotta have it 1,2. I tried some of the other answers on the page, even though they did give me my correct inputs my AMS learning said it was wrong

Comment: The problem with passing in 1,2,3 etc is that you have an indeterminate number of parameters. So you would likely need to use the arguments object to put the parameters into  an array, then do the same thing as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you should either pass an array to `countUniqueItems` or use the `arguments` keyword in the for-loop.

Your code is only seeing `1` (as `arr` inside the function).

Comment: Im really new how do I parse an array I looked it up and it was confusing to me

Answer (score 0):

basic implementation to find unique items

```
function countUniqueItems(...arr) {
  let nums = [];
  for (let num of arr) {
    if (nums.indexOf(num) === -1) nums.push(num);
  }
  return nums;
}
console.log(countUniqueItems(1, 2, 1));
```

Comment: very helpful as well i wish i was able to write it that short

Comment: with the time u can

Answer (score 0):

Using Set you can remove the duplicate values, you dont need to do logic run the loop to find the unique values from array.

```
const a = [1,2,3,3]; 
const uniqueSet = new Set(a);
uniqueSet.size

let uniqueFinder = arr => { const uniqueSet = new Set(arr); return uniqueSet.size}
const arrywithduplicates = [1,2,3,3,4,4];
uniqueFinder(arrywithduplicates) // return 4
```

Read more about Set : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set